# Group project forgot to pull before i pushed

Tags: git, gitlab

so im working togheter with some people from school and wrote some code to the project and then tried to push it. I then realised that i didnt pull before i pushed and an error message appeared:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    .idea/misc.xml
```

Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.

So i tried to commit instead and got this:

```
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 15 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   .idea/misc.xml
    modified:   src/Road.java
```

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

It has worked without problems until i messed up and since it's a group project im kinda unsure how much i just wanna test from simular problems i find online. This is my second time using git bash so i know very little about what i can do and what affect my commands has to the project.
Thanks for all help!

Edit: I know the other people that works on the project has pushed some new code into the project and really dont wanna mess anything up for them

Comment: one handy general tip, consider using the **Sourcetree** app rather than command line

Comment: @Fattie why shall he use a proprietary GUI necessarily that is only available on Windows and Mac instead of command line which is available everywhere?

Comment: @AshokArora - it's a good way for OP to learn the basics

Comment: @Fattie How is **that** better for OP to learn the basics? GUI hides a lot of things which clearly he should be learning to handle since the beginning. command line is a good way to learn the basics.

Comment: hi @AshokArora !  You're clearly extremely dedicated to the CLI.  Good for you - enjoy that.

Answer (score 0):

## Information

`git branches` are suitable when working in a group scenario.

The model of working is that every new `feature` gets it's own branch and you issue issue a `pull request` when the work on that branch is completed.

That `pull request` is reviewed by other members and then `merged` into the `master` branch.

## Answer

`git stash` is a handy command for what happened in your case.

on the master branch, run `git stash`, this command will hold your changes in another `branch` while also cleaning the current `branch`.

Now, you can `git pull` to recieve changes from the `master` branch.

Then you can create another branch with `git branch -b branch_name`.

Now we will apply those `stashed` changes to this branch with `git stash apply`.

Edit #1: I had assumed that you have `staged` your changes. If not, then before `git stash`, `stage` them by running `git add -A`.

Comment: Running git stash says "No local changes to save"

Comment: @forsb `git add -A` to save your local changes

Answer (score 0):

It seems like one of your team mates have accidentally committed the `.idea/misc.xml` file.

Based on what you wrote in another comment, I assume this file is untracked in your local repository
(this means it shows as "untracked" when you do `git status`).

I would check what the difference is between your local version of the file,
and the one on the remote repository (e.g. check on GitLab website).

If you determine that you can use the `.idea/misc.xml` from the remote repisitory,
and this file is in fact untracked in your local repo,
then you can simply delete your local file `rm .idea/misc.xml` and then `git pull` should succeed.

If this file includes information which only works on your team mates' computer,
then you will instead want to have it removed from the remote repository, and ignored from version control (added to the `.gitignore` file). This is a bit tricky for *you* to do, since you're working on the `master` branch already.

If you want to combine your local `.idea/misc.xml` and your team mates `.idea/misc.xml`,
then you should commit your `.idea/misc.xml` file before you `git pull`.
I.e.

```
git add .idea/misc.xml
git commit -m "add idea misc config file"
git pull
```

This *might* give you a merge conflict.

Sooo, it depends.